# Should I show users their IP address?

Tags: privacy, addresses

I run a small cybersecurity blog, with a big focus on privacy and anti-tracking. I have a prominent statement at the top of my homepage that there is no tracking on the site (which is true).

One idea that I have had is to add to the site footer something like:

```
You are browsing from: 127.0.0.1 (IPv4)
```

As well as:

```
You are browsing using the Tor Hidden Service (Onion)
```

On a technical level, this information is not an invasion of privacy since there isn't really a way for me to serve content without knowing the user's IP address at some point (except for Tor, etc).

I guess the argument would be that I should be doing as little as possible with the data, i.e. not displaying it on the page, sending it back to them unnecessarily, etc.

I will not be collecting IP addresses and sending them to a marketing company or anything like that. Showing the connecting IP at the bottom just seems like something that might fit the site.

My question is how would this come across to a user? My audience is mainly technical however it still might feel a bit like:

```
"Oh, thanks for doing that with **my** IP address."
```

I've been thinking about this for a while and I am aware this sounds like a bad idea, I almost think that myself, however I have very little knowledge in UX so I thought that I would ask here before binning the idea all together!

Any suggestions or feedback is much appreciated.

Thank you.

Comment: Why do you want to put such a thing on the page to begin with?

Comment: It's something that I personally like to see, so that I know where the site is seeing me come from. I generally think that people reading my blog are similar to me, so maybe they'd like it too? I am not sure overall to be honest, it's just an idea I am trying to either tick off or leave for another time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm a little confused about your goals here. You're actively trying to communicate with your audience that you are not tracking nor selling their information. Adding a message like `"You are browsing from: 127.0.0.1 (IPv4)"` ruins your attempt at maintaining integrity.

I'm sure your audience knows you can't really do anything with an IP address alone, but it likely does make them question your intentions. **"Why is he telling me this? What is he doing or not telling me?"** Don't run the risk of alienating your audience just because of a silly addition. You want to build trust, not raise suspicion. Your gut feeling telling you this might backfire is already telling you what you need to know.

Comment: `Don't run the risk of alienating your audience just because of a silly addition.` Thanks for your help.